# How to get vscode to recognize react native destructured attributes?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

I had this code:

```
const Ticket = ({ ticket }) => (
  <TicketWrapper>
    <Title>{ticket.Title}</Title>
    <Body>{ticket.Body}</Body>
  </TicketWrapper>
);
```

but it was failing silently due to the fact that `ticket` should have had uncapitalized attributes, i.e.

```
const Ticket = ({ ticket }) => (
  <TicketWrapper>
    <Title>{ticket.title}</Title>
    <Body>{ticket.body}</Body>
  </TicketWrapper>
);
```

and also in editing, I don't get auto-complete suggestions for the attributes (regardless of capitalization!).

This made my mistake here *really* hard to spot !

I have extensions for both react and react native installed and active.

[image]

but they are not helping with this issue.

How to get vs code to help me here?

Comment: What *is* ticket? Do you have propTypes, flow, typescript or anything else for the type information to come from that would tell your tooling what props it has?

Answer (score 0):

In typescript I have the `@types/react` package installed as part of the project (create-react-app added it) which allows me to do this:

```
export interface TicketType {
    title: string;
    body: string;
}

export interface TicketProps {
  ticket: TicketType;
}

const Ticket: React.FC<TicketProps> = ({ ticket}) => {
    // ticket is of type TicketType and can use
    // use ticket.title and ticket.body
}
```

If you are not using typescript you should check out [proptypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html):

Comment: *Is* the OP using TypeScript? Note that @types/react just provides the type headers for core React, like FC, it's TS that allows you to write and use the interfaces.